# HBase "between" Filters

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to retrieve rows with in range, using Filter List but I'm not successful.
Below is my code snippet.

I want to retrieve data between 1000 and 2000.

HTable table = new HTable(conf, "TRAN_DATA");

```
    List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<Filter>();

    SingleColumnValueFilter filter1 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("TRAN"),
              Bytes.toBytes("TRAN_ID"),
              CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER, new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("1000")));
    filter1.setFilterIfMissing(true);
    filters.add(filter1);

    SingleColumnValueFilter filter2 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("TRAN"),
              Bytes.toBytes("TRAN_ID"),
              CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS,new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("2000")));

    filters.add(filter2);

    FilterList filterList = new FilterList(filters);

    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.setFilter(filterList);
    ResultScanner scanner1 = table.getScanner(scan);

    System.out.println("Results of scan #1 - MUST_PASS_ALL:");
    int n = 0;

    for (Result result : scanner1) {
        for (KeyValue kv : result.raw()) {
            System.out.println("KV: " + kv + ", Value: "
                    + Bytes.toString(kv.getValue()));
        {
            n++;

        }
    }
    scanner1.close();
```

Tried with all possible ways using
1.   SingleColumnValueFilter filter2 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("TRANSACTIONS"),
                      Bytes.toBytes("TRANS_ID"),
                      CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS, new SubstringComparator("5000"));

1. SingleColumnValueFilter filter2 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("TRANSACTIONS"),
                     Bytes.toBytes("TRANS_ID"),
                     CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS, Bytes.toBytes("5000"));                                                        None of above approaches work :(

Comment: I'm not getting correct results, not sure if there is another way of implementing the same, as most of filters in hbase are row filters, how to add filters on specific columns to retrieve data

Comment: Are you storing the keys as byte values of the string or bytes value of Int/Long?

Comment: @Arnon - Everything I'm storing as bytes,using HBase Put Api to call add method to store values which only allows bytes[] to be set against a column, is there other way to store Int/Long values

Comment: Everything is bytes in HBase but numbers can be stored as characters or values e.g. one can be stored as the character "1" or as the byte 0x01 (like hbase does with Increment qualifiers)

Comment: @Arnon yes I'm aware of it, but if you see, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Increment api it allows to addColumn with Long value, but there is no way to do the same using org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put api and when I tried adding Long values using Put api it stores in\x0 format but when I try to retrieve it, it prints as unknown character.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help I got it working now...

Comment: @shahsanket what have you gotten the solution for your above problem?

Answer (score 2):

One thing which is certainly off here is when creating the FILTERLIST you also have to specify FilterList.Operator, otherwise not sure how filterlist would handle multiple filters. In your case it should be something like :-

```
FilterList filterList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL, filters);
```

See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK. Check if you have persisted them as "1000" and "2000" not as byte[] for 1000 and 2000.

Rest looks fine to me.

Comment: Tried with all possible ways using                                        1.  new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("TRANSACTIONS"),
                Bytes.toBytes("TRANS_ID"),
                CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS, new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("5000")));

Answer (score 0):

1 FilterList default operator is Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL. It's ok of your code about this.
2 If you put the string as bytes in hbase, your choice is wrong.
  because "1000"  < "2" < "5000"

```
    Put put = new Put(rowKey_ForTest);
    put.add(ColumnFamilyName, QName1, Bytes.toBytes("2"));
    table.put(put);

    List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<Filter>();
    SingleColumnValueFilter filter1 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
            ColumnFamilyName, QName1, CompareOp.GREATER,
            new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("1000")));
    filters.add(filter1);

    SingleColumnValueFilter filter2 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
            ColumnFamilyName, QName1, CompareOp.LESS, new BinaryComparator(
                    Bytes.toBytes("5000")));

    filters.add(filter2);

    FilterList filterList = new FilterList(filters);

    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.setFilter(filterList);

    List<String> resultRowKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
    ResultScanner resultScanner = table.getScanner(scan);
    for (Result result = resultScanner.next(); result != null; result = resultScanner
            .next()) {
        resultRowKeys.add(Bytes.toString(result.getRow()));
    }
    Util.close(resultScanner);

    Assert.assertEquals(1, resultRowKeys.size());
```

3 If you put the int as bytes, your code is wrong.
  You should use Bytes.toBytes(int), not Bytes.toBytes(String).

My test code is on https://github.com/zhang-xzhi/simplehbase
There is a lot of test about hbase.

Or you can post your put code, so we can check how did you save your data to hbase.
Or you can debug it, check your value's format.

See if it can help.