# checkAndPut always succeeds

Tags: java, hadoop, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I am keeping a counter in bigtable, and want to put some data in when the counter reaches X. I am Currently doing it like this:

```
Put put = new Put(EXAMPLE_ROW_KEY);
put.addColumn(EXAMPLE_COLUMN_FAMILY, NEW_QUALIFIER, NEW_VALUE);

boolean success = table.checkAndPut(EXAMPLE_ROW_KEY, 
                                    INFO_COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME,
                                    SIZE_COLUMN,
                                    CompareFilter.CompareOp.LESS, 
                                    Bytes.toBytes(10000L), put);
```

The issue is, that success is always true and new value is always put, even though the size exceeds 10000L. I tried to use  `CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL` with the exact same values and it was still true.

Is the checkAndPut not supported by bigtable, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was, that I was using the dependency `bigtable-hbase-1.2:0.9.6.2`, which probably collided with another dependency. This, I assume, caused an incorrect `CheckAndMutateRequest` to be sent silently and the check in `checkAndPut` to always pass. I switched to  `bigtable-hbase-1.2:0.9.2` and everything is evaluted correctly.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the update. I'm glad you are unblocked but it does seems like that might also indicate a regression so the Cloud Bigtable engineering team will investigate this further.

Answer (score 1):

We do support the table.checkAndPut operation in Cloud Bigtable.

However in general it isn't a great practice to try and use the CompareFilter this way since it is performing lexical comparison on the bytes, not a logical integer comparison.

For more information and context see:

- [How to use filters over atomic counter in hbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632835/how-to-use-filters-over-atomic-counter-in-hbase)
- [Simple integer comparison in HBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926813/simple-integer-comparison-in-hbase)
- [HBase "between" Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429412/hbase-between-filters)
- http://apache-hbase.679495.n3.nabble.com/Filters-failing-to-compare-negative-numbers-int-float-double-or-long-td4057268.html

As far as the main HBase API, there are plans to handle this better in future HBase versions, e.g. in the proposed HBase 2.0 which incorporates a new OrderedBytes datatype inspired by the orderly project:

- https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/OrderedBytes.html
- https://github.com/ndimiduk/orderly

In the meantime you might be able to incorporate orderly somehow, or perhaps use an HBase counter and the increment operation.

Comment: Thanks, for the clarification. I modified the code to only check for equality on a string, but unfortunately I get the same incorrect results. The check succeeds even though the values are different.

Comment: You can track progress on this issue here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/1348.